# jersey - exception Mapper is not catching 400 errors.

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, hibernate-validator

I was trying to map my validation error to exception mapper but it is not catching up.The page shows HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request.
     below is my mapper code.

```
@Provider
public class UnexpectedExceptionMapper implements 
ExceptionMapper<Exception> {


@Override
public Response toResponse(Exception e) {


        return Response
         .status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode())
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .entity("validation Exception : " + e.getMessage() + "error code :" + Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode())
                .build();
    }
```

The below is the resource file code.

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Settings updateSettings(@Valid SettingsForm settingsForm) {
  return SettingsDAO.updateSettings(settingsForm);

}
```

I was using Hibernate validator.Form class is below:

```
public class SettingsForm {
@NotNull
private int sensorLogCollectionInterval;
@NotNull
private int sensorConnectionErrorCount;
@NotNull
private boolean analysisServerEnabled;
@Pattern(regexp = "^(https?:\\/\\/)?((\\w+\\.)?\\w+\\.\\w+|\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}(:\\d{1,5})?)(\\/)?([^\\.\\s\\,])*$")
private String analysisServerUrl;
@Size(min = 1, max = 20)
private String analysisServerCompanyId;
//getters and setter//
}
```

I need to validation erros as json. Can anyone help me.

Comment: For bean validation, Jersey uses an ExceptionMapper for ValidationException, which is more specific than Exception. That's why you're isn't called.

Comment: Actually, I figure it out , the problem was resolved by adding

    property(BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);

thankyou.

Comment: still i it doesnt caught 401,403,405 error.need a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Application class with the getClasses override? If so, add the Exception mapper to the set of classes to be exposed in the Rest Service. Otherwise, if you are using package scanning, then add the @Provider annotation.

Comment: is it a comment or a answer  ?

Comment: My reputation didnt allow me to add comments to the original post. That is why I wanted to contribute to this Question by adding an answer.